# Angular with REST in Spring BOOT

Tags: java, angular, rest

On my `index.html` I have button : `<button><a href="/rest/teachers/getAll" class="click-me" target="_blank" type="button">Teachers</a></button>`.

And after I click on It I receive JSON object with help of REST :

```
  @RestController
public class TeacherRestController {

private static final String TEACHER_MODEL = "teacher";

 @GetMapping("/rest/teachers/getAll")
public List<Teacher> getAllTeachers() {
    return teacherService.getAll();
}
```

I need to establish interaction between my REST Controller and Front-End - maybe it can be Angular.

In my case I want not only to get JSON objects, I need to get some html page from my project and here send data from rest.

I don't understand how properly I can introduce Angular with help of this link https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-angularjs/
but I think that Angular can help me..

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: That link refers to angularjs. That is **not** the same as angular.

Comment: @NicholasK But this link was recommended for me and I thought that It can help but I can't realize all that I see in this link, in my project..

Answer (score 0):

You already have a REST, you should start will an angular project and you do not need to add anything to your java project currently.

Start an angular project
use HttpClient to receive data from server and display that in your components.

Comment: Now it is difficult for me to understand, maybe you have some links to read..
I didn't find information that can help me.

Comment: You can read angular guide from here https://angular.io/ perhaps you need someone to do the frontend for you.